# VFS UK Biometrics Appointment

Tags: visas

Has anyone had a biometrics appointment at USCIS for UK visa?
What happens at the appointment?
What do they do if they cannot capture your fingerprints?
Many thanks for all assistance.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be able to capture your fingerprints?

Comment: Having taken fingerprints myself in the past, I know you do get people whose prints are not legible. Some would be migrants file away their prints to prevent being identified, and some musicians have very worn prints (if they play on instruments with steel strings). And you get people who have injured their hands. In most cases folk were told to come back in 4 weeks time when things may have improved. 

In extreme cases (eg to do with keeping a record of a criminal suspect, it is possible to take the toes instead).

If they can’t take your prints it’s likely to delay the visa.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to think this situation may apply to you?